# Android SQLite query is always empty

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

So right now I'm using this solution in my app [Ship an application with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database/4810185#4810185)

In my main activity, I just want to test to make sure that the database is working, so all I'm doing it a simply query to get some names, all I did was add 3 lines(commented where I added them):

```
       DatabaseHelper myDbHelper;
       SQLiteDatabase myDb = null;

       myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
       /*
        * Database must be initialized before it can be used. This will ensure
        * that the database exists and is the current version.
        */
        myDbHelper.initializeDataBase();
        Cursor c;
        String s = null;
        try {
           // A reference to the database can be obtained after initialization.
           myDb = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
//the next 3 lines are all I added
           c = myDb.rawQuery("select name from breads", null);
           s = c.getString(1);
           c.close();
           /*
            * Place code to use database here.
            */
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
           try {
               myDbHelper.close();
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           } finally {
               myDb.close();
           }
       }
```

However, s just remains empty. If I do the exact same query `select name from breads` in the console, I will get data. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: define empty please. Do you mean an empty string or null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myDb = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
//the next 3 lines are all I added
c = myDb.rawQuery("select name from breads", null);
c.moveToFirst(); // ADD THIS
s = c.getString(1);
c.close();
```